# Power Apps : This formula uses scope, which is not presently supported for evaluation

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have a SharePoint list displayed in a Gallery in Power Apps, If i try to display anything in a Text control inside the Gallery, the text appear but with an error : "This formula uses scope, which is not presently supported for evaluation",

1- Since it's not supported for evaluation, I cannot apply some logic there. Is there any workaround to surpace this issue ?

The exact situation I am looking for, is that I have a Question list (ID, Question, Type, etc) plus a Lookup column called "RelatedQuestion" that point to a parent question inside the same list.

2- the appearance of this subquestions inside the gallery depends on the answer choosed on the parent question, am I missing something ?

Thank you.

Comment: ThisItem : This formula uses scope, which is not presently supported for evaluation, I can see that the error reside on ThisItem !!!